# how do i change the colour of a trianglelist in directx 11

Tags: c++, directx

I believe that I have the correct code to colour in a triangle in DirectX, but it still doesn't change colour - instead, it simply keeps displaying a yellow triangle.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please take the time to read this: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . It is easier for use to help when we are able to understand the problem.

Comment: This is a new one. A picture of a word document containing a link?

Comment: it was being awkward and not letting me post my code or a link to the code

Comment: As you are new to DirectX, you should take a look at [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started). It can be challenging to learn the entire rendering pipeline and HLSL all at once, so DirectXTK lets you start with a working pipeline and then dig into each area while still getting something besides a black screen.

Answer (score 2):

There are numerous ways to go about changing the draw color with a programmable shading pipeline, but one solution that's easy to implement is to use per-vertex colors.

In your input layout, you need to add a color value:

```
// C++
const D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC InputElements[] =
{
    { "SV_Position", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT,    0, D3D11_APPEND_ALIGNED_ELEMENT, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
    { "COLOR",       0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT, 0, D3D11_APPEND_ALIGNED_ELEMENT, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
};
```

Then your vertex is something like:

```
// C++
struct Vertex
{
    XMFLOAT3 position;
    XMFLOAT4 color;
};
```

You then pass the color you want to each triangle, typically copying the same value at each corner unless you want the triangles to be drawn as a gradient.

```
// C++
static const Vertex s_vertexData[3] =
{
    { { 0.0f,   0.5f,  0.5f, 1.0f },{ 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f } },  // Top / Red
    { { 0.5f,  -0.5f,  0.5f, 1.0f },{ 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f } },  // Right / Green
    { { -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f, 1.0f },{ 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f } }   // Left / Blue
};
```

You also have to ensure your Vertex Shader reads the color out of the vertex and passes it along to the Pixel Shader:

```
// HLSL
struct VS_INPUT
{
    float4 Pos : SV_POSITIION;
    float4 Color : COLOR;
};

struct PS_INPUT
{
    float4 Pos : SV_POSITION;
    float4 Color : COLOR;
};

PS_INPUT VS( VS_INPUT input )
{
    PS_INPUT output;
    output.Pos = input.Pos;
    output.Color = input.Color;
    return output;
}
```

And your Pixel Shader has to use the color value in some way:

```
// HLSL
float4 PS( PS_INPUT input) : SV_Target
{
    return input.Color;
}
```

> As you appear to be very new to DirectX, I'd recommend looking at the [DirectX Tool Kit tutorials](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started) as well as the *Introductory Graphics* samples on [Xbox-ATG-Samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/Xbox-ATG-Samples) and `SimpleTriangle` in particular.

Comment: for some reason it is saying that float4 and PS_INPUT are undefined

Comment: Are you trying to build HLSL code as C++?

Comment: i think so, i don't really know what that means

Comment: I thin that i put the code in the right place (the errors have gone) but the triangles colour is still the basic yellow it hasnt changed